# The number of ways a set, n, can be partitioned into disjoint non-empty sets where the union is the entire set n.

Tags: combinatorics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMalo.png)

1. For any integer $n > 1$, let $r_n$ denote the number of different ways that the set $[n] := \{1, \ldots, n\}$ can be partitioned into disjoint non-empty subsets, the union of which is the entire set [$n]$.

For example, $r_3 = 5$. This is because the set $\{1,2,3\}$ can be partitioned in precisely the following $5$ distinct ways: $\{\{1\}, \{2\},\{3\}\} ; \{\{1\}, \{2,3\}\} ; \{\{2\}, \{1,3\}\} ; \{\{3\}, \{1,2\}\} ;  \{\{1,2,3\}\}$. Prove that, for all even integers $n$, $(n/2)^{n/2} \leq r_n ≤ n^n$.

(Hint: for establishing the lower bound, suppose you only count those partitions in which each of the numbers $1, 2, \ldots, n/2$ is in a separate part of the partition.)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Also, For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Note that $r_n$ is the $n$-th [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number)